# Controller Properties extended from base class persist

Tags: ember.js

I’m a little confused about something in Ember with the object model, specifically relating to controllers. I have a base class with a property that is an array and I’m extending two controllers from the base class. The array on the base class seems to persist across both instances of the base class; although, I thought Ember would make them two separate instances of the class. Crude example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/firovahoxera/1/

Shouldn’t the base class instantiate as two different instances or am I thinking about this wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array's are objects in the sense that adding it to the controller adds a reference to that array to all instances of the controller.

If you want an instance on all of your controllers you can create the array on init.

```
App.BaseClassController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  setupPersists: function(){
    this.set('persists', []);
  }.on('init')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/firovahoxera/2/edit